# Class player - Animation stop first frame

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

Quick question. I have my Player Class, working perfectly. Except for a small detail. This is the class:

```
from dict.entity_dict import player, player_class
from collections import OrderedDict
import pyglet, random

key = pyglet.window.key

class Player(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):

    dir_stand = "south"
    dir_run = "south"
    sprite_stand = 3
    sprite_run = 3
    image = None
    s = 0

    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game

        self.keyboard = key.KeyStateHandler()

        self.statistics_base = OrderedDict()

        self.image_stand = pyglet.resource.image(player.get("player_stand", {'x': None}).get("resource"))
        self.image_run = pyglet.resource.image(player.get("player_run", {'x': None}).get("resource"))
        self.image_stand_width = player.get("player_stand", {'x': None}).get("width")
        self.image_stand_height = player.get("player_stand", {'x': None}).get("height")
        self.image_run_width = player.get("player_run", {'x': None}).get("width")
        self.image_run_height = player.get("player_run", {'x': None}).get("height")

        self.vx = self.game.wd / 2
        self.vy = self.game.wh / 2

        self.load_sprite()

    def class_player(self, type):
        self.statistics_base["hp"] = player_class.get(type, {'x': None}).get("hp")
        self.statistics_base["atk"] = player_class.get(type, {'x': None}).get("atk")
        self.statistics_base["dif"] = player_class.get(type, {'x': None}).get("dif")
        self.statistics_base["atk_sp"] = player_class.get(type, {'x': None}).get("atk_sp")
        self.statistics_base["dif_sp"] = player_class.get(type, {'x': None}).get("dif_sp")
        self.statistics_base["vel"] = player_class.get(type, {'x': None}).get("vel")
        for stat in self.statistics_base:
            if self.statistics_base[stat] is None:
                self.statistics_base[stat] = 10


    def animation(self, image, da, width, height):
        frame_list = [image.get_region(x=width * i, y=height * da, width=46, height=58) for i in range(22)]
        image_animation = pyglet.image.Animation.from_image_sequence(frame_list, 0.10, True)

        return image_animation

    def direction_sprite(self):
        if self.dir_stand == "north":
            self.sprite_stand = 7
        elif self.dir_stand == "east":
            self.sprite_stand = 5
        elif self.dir_stand == "south":
            self.sprite_stand = 3
        elif self.dir_stand == "west":
            self.sprite_stand = 1
        if self.dir_run == "north":
            self.sprite_run = 7
        elif self.dir_run == "north-east":
            self.sprite_run = 6
        elif self.dir_run == "east":
            self.sprite_run = 5
        elif self.dir_run == "south-east":
            self.sprite_run = 4
        elif self.dir_run == "south":
            self.sprite_run = 3
        elif self.dir_run == "south-west":
            self.sprite_run = 2
        elif self.dir_run == "west":
            self.sprite_run = 1
        elif self.dir_run == "north-west":
            self.sprite_run = 0

    def load_sprite(self):
        if not self.keyboard[key.W] and not self.keyboard[key.S] and not self.keyboard[key.D] and not self.keyboard[key.A]:
            self.keyboard.clear()
            img = self.image_stand
            img_width = self.image_stand_width
            img_height = self.image_stand_height
            da = self.sprite_stand
        else:
            img = self.image_run
            img_width = self.image_run_width
            img_height = self.image_run_height
            da = self.sprite_run

        self.direction_sprite()
        self.image = self.animation(img, da, img_width, img_height)
        self.image.width, self.image.height = img_width, img_height
        self.image.anchor_x, self.image.anchor_y = img_width // 2, img_height // 2

        self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.image, batch=self.game.Batch, group=self.game.GroupEntitySprite)


        self.sprite.x = self.vx
        self.sprite.y = self.vy

    def key_player(self):
        if self.keyboard[key.W]:
            self.vy += 1
            self.dir_stand = "north"
            self.dir_run = "north"
        if self.keyboard[key.S]:
            self.vy -= 1
            self.dir_stand = "south"
            self.dir_run = "south"
        if self.keyboard[key.D]:
            self.vx += 1
            self.dir_stand = "east"
            self.dir_run = "east"
        if self.keyboard[key.A]:
            self.vx -= 1
            self.dir_stand = "west"
            self.dir_run = "west"
        if self.keyboard[key.W] and self.keyboard[key.D]:
            random1 = random.randint(1, 2)
            if random1 == 1:
                self.dir_stand = "north"
            else:
                self.dir_stand = "east"
            self.dir_run = "north-east"
        if self.keyboard[key.S] and self.keyboard[key.D]:
            random2 = random.randint(1, 2)
            if random2 == 1:
                self.dir_stand = "south"
            else:
                self.dir_stand = "east"
            self.dir_run = "south-east"
        if self.keyboard[key.W] and self.keyboard[key.A]:
            random3 = random.randint(1, 2)
            if random3 == 1:
                self.dir_stand = "north"
            else:
                self.dir_stand = "west"
            self.dir_run = "north-west"
        if self.keyboard[key.S] and self.keyboard[key.A]:
            random4 = random.randint(1, 2)
            if random4 == 1:
                self.dir_stand = "south"
            else:
                self.dir_stand = "west"
            self.dir_run = "south-west"

    def update(self):
        self.key_player()
        self.load_sprite()
```

Since to update the Player's sprite, I need to call the "load_sprite" function, which causes the animation to be constantly called. As a result, the same animation does not appear and remains still at the first frame. So how could I solve?

Edit: Modified the script, including the for loop. If you see, I modified the group, using Batch and OrderedGroup instead. In this way we can clearly see the problem I am having.

The problem I have is due to the fact that pyglet.sprite.Sprite is called in order to update which animation is executed. However, doing so at the same time, the animations are not shown exactly because of the constant call of pyglet.sprite.Sprite.

[image]

Comment: You're trying to cram too much into this class. I would suggest (at minimum) to not let the player handle the loading of sprites. Load the images outside the class and pass them into the player's initializer (or even better, pass the `Animation` object). This will help you separate concerns and you'll probably circumvent the problem of constantly having to load the images when updating the player. I would also suggest using a for loop in your `animation` method, so it becomes more dynamic, less code and easier to read.

Comment: the for loop does not work, I tried in different ways, but either gives me error, or the animation is not shown. I thought about using imagegrid, but I still have not figured out how to do it.

Comment: Even if I passed the animation from the main class to the player class, I would still have the same problem. The sprite must be reloaded to be changed, but doing this, I would have the same problem. The only alternative, using your advice, would be to create different players how many animations to change and make them invisible. But I would avoid such a thing, it would be a useless excess of entity.

Comment: Why does the sprite need to reloaded? If I read your code correctly, it seems you're calling the `animation` method in order to change between the standing animation and the running animation. You should be able to load both these animations and just switch between them, rather than reloading them each time.

Comment: Btw, this should work for the `animation` method: `frame_list = [image.get_region(x=width * i, y=height * da, width=46, height=58) for i in range(20)]`.

Comment: In the Player Class, if it moves in one of the eight directions (north, north-east, east, etc.) it has eight different animations that show the direction in which it is proceeding. If the Player is stationary, it has four animations (north, east, south, west). So, I need to reload the sprite every time to show the new animation. But doing this, I find the problem I have described.

Comment: Exactly, so you have a total of 12 animations for each direction and whether the player is standing or running. So you can create 12 animation objects (using `pyglet.image.Animation.from_image_sequence`) directly, instead of recreating them every time the animation changes. And when you have these animations you could just switch between them. For example `if self.dir_run == 'south': self.current_animation = self.running_south_animation`.

Comment: Precisely, but even if I create the first twelve animations, or create twelve players from the main class and make them invisible (which I would like to avoid, for the amount of entities and a decline of fps), or I have to update the sprite every time I have to change the animation. But the problem is due to the fact that I have to call pyglet.sprite.Sprite constantly, which blocks the sprite at the first frame

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can change the sprite's animation by setting its `image` attribute, instead of creating a new Sprite instance. Second, only change its animation when you actually need to. That is when the direction changes.

I've added a simple example (pseudo) code to roughly show what I mean.

```
def animation(image, da, width, height):
    frame_list = [image.get_region(x=width * i, y=height * da, width=46, height=58) for i in range(22)]
    image_animation = pyglet.image.Animation.from_image_sequence(frame_list, 0.10, True)
    return image_animation


class Player:

    def __init__(self, standing_animations, running_animations):
        # ... code ...
        self.standing_animations = standing_animations   # List of animations 
        self.running_animations  = running_animations    # List of animations
        self.current_animation = standing_animations[0]  # Just to have a default animation
        self.previous_running_direction  = None
        self.previous_standing_direction = None

    def load_sprite(self):
        self.sprite.x = self.vx
        self.sprite.y = self.vy

        if self.previous_running_direction == self.dir_run and self.previous_standing_direction == self.dir_stand:
            return  # Don't do anything more in here

        if not self.keyboard[key.W] and not self.keyboard[key.S] and not self.keyboard[key.D] and not self.keyboard[key.A]:
            self.keyboard.clear()
            self.current_animation = self.standing_animations[self.sprite_stand]
        else:
            self.current_animation = self.running_animations[self.sprite_run]

        self.sprite.image = self.current_animation

    def update(self):
        self.previous_running_direction  = self.dir_run
        self.previous_standing_direction = self.dir_stand
        self.key_player()
        self.load_sprite()
```

Comment: I did partly as you said, modifying a bit both my original class and the one you suggested. I solved it, but now a new problem has come out that I'm trying to solve.